# Attachment for viewing the sun with a telescope

Tags: telescope, solar-eclipse

In 2016 I got to see the transit of Mercury thanks to a group of volunteer astronomers. The astronomer had a device attached to the telescope eyepiece that allowed the light to project onto frosted glass.

I’d like to get such a device for my own telescope for viewing the next two solar eclipses, but I don’t know what this device is called. I’ve Googled various things, but I’ve had no luck.

Comment: I used a sun funnel for the partial solar eclipse in 2017. It worked far better than I expected, even with my awful cheap old telescope. See here for a link: https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/make-sun-funnel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The device you saw was probably a "solar projection eyepiece". You can use any eyepiece for this, in theory, though eyepieces with cemented lenses can heat up in the sun and the glass can crack.
Personally I wouldn't feel comfortable using one of those with my telescope.

Instead:

You can use solar film specially designed for looking at the sun, such as Baader's ["AstroSolar Safety Film"](https://www.baader-planetarium.com/en/astrosolar-safety-film-od-5.0-(20x29-100x50-117x117-cm).html) which comes in a variety of sizes.

The link above is for just the film, but if you want to use it with a telescope then they also sell the film [mounted in a frame](https://www.baader-planetarium.com/en/solar/whitelight/astf-astrosolar-telescope-filter-od-5.0-(80mm---280mm).html) which clips onto the front of your telescope.

Further down the line, if you get more into solar observation, then you may want to look into buying a [Herschel Wedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel_wedge) which filters the light after it's passed through the telescope, so shows more detail.